# Cannot fetch data from mongodb using rust mongodb driver

Tags: database, mongodb, rust

```
    match collection.find_one(doc! {"index": "1"}, None).await {
        Ok(Some(user)) => println!("{:?}", user),
        Ok(None) => println!("none"),
        Err(err) => println!("{:?}", err),
    };
```

i get an error

> Error { kind: BsonDeserialization(DeserializationError { message:
> "invalid type: map, expected a string" }), labels: {}, wire_version:
> None, source: None }

Comment: What does the type of `user` look like and what does the data you are expecting back look like? The error indicates there is a mismatch where an object was returned where a field expected a string